# C# directives & namespace problem

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

I have a problem here. I have a **class library** namely **ClLib**, and has the following **8 cs** files.

- Express *(parent class)*
         - 1E1
         - 1E2
         - 1E3
- Normal (parent class)
         - 1N1
         - 1N2
         - 1N3

Also, a method is also included in each 8 class file. For example,

```
public class 1E1:Express
{
    public int subtractNumExp1E1(int firstNum, int secNum)
    {
        return firstNum - secNum;
    }
}
```

The 1E1:Express is used to display the relationship between the parent class(Express) and subclass (1E1).

I have also created a Windows App in Visual Studio, and I need to create a directive like "using ClLib.Express.1E1". How do I go about it? I am stuck in this situation whereby when I want to change the namespace of 1E1 from "namespace ClLib" to "namespace ClLib.Express.1E1". An error occurs, as the namespace ClLib has already contain one definition for Express.

A great thanks and appreciation in advance for all kind souls who are willing to help me:)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a type and a namespace with the same name ("CILib.Express").

If you want a `CILib.Express` namespace, the **simplest** option is to move/rename the `CILib.Express` type.

You can, however, also have nested types. You could, for example, have:

```
namespace CILib {
    public class Express {
        public class SomeType {}
    }
}
```

If separate files are a concern:

file 1:

```
namespace CILib {
    public partial class Express { 
        // "Express" code
    }
}
```

file 2:

```
namespace CILib {
    public partial class Express {
        public class SomeType {
            // "SomeType" code
        }
    }
}
```

However, `using` directives only relate to namespaces; I don't think you could have `using CILib.Express`, as that is a type not a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you just have to delete the namespace `ClLib` and make sure that there is exactly one copy of `ClLib.Express.1E1`

P/S: Are you sure that the proper namespace is `ClLib.Express.1E1`? `1E1` is a cs file, and it's usually a class. So you don't have to write `using ClLib.Express`,  that would be sufficient.

Comment: You mean delete namespace ClLib  of which file?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is confusion around the namespace and base class.

Namespace:  ClLib.Express
Class: public class 1E1:Express

Rename your base class to ExpressBase to differentiate it.

If you need to reference the namespace:

using ClLib.Express

Hope I have understood your project structure!